# Strange white outline around two corners of a gradient

Tags: html, css

In HTML I have a div that has a border radius of 20px. I have a layer in the div that i have set to cover the entire div (i am going to make it into a hover effect later). For some reason on the gradient background of the layer in the div, on the two bottom corners there is a strange white outline. I have tried making the gradient bigger but did not help.
your text
here is my css for the outside div:

```
.project {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 350px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    margin: 10px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    vertical-align: center;
}
.layer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), rgb(0, 0, 0));
    background-clip: padding-box;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    outline-offset: -20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: [edit] to add the necessary HTML in order to create a [mcve].

Comment: Not reproducible. I nested `div.layer` inside `div.project` but did not see a white outline.

Comment: This may depend on what browser/system is being used as it sounds like a sort of edge effect (akin to a rounding error when the system is mapping CSS pixels to screen pixels). What browser/OS are you using? When you add the runnable snippet to your question please check is definitely demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.